# Line integral interval question.

Tags: sequences-and-series, line-integrals

I have something confusing from a lecture that I'm watching:

Consider this integral:

$$\int_c \frac{dz}{z(z-2)^4}$$

The contour is $C: |z-2| = 1$

So this circle, graphically, is centered at 2 with a radius of 1.

I am told this function is analytic everywhere except for two places: 0 and 2. The 0 is outside the circle and the 2 is inside the circle/domain since the circle is centered at 2. So the circle is a punctured disk.

In my lecture I am told that the interval $0 \lt \left | (z-2) \right | \lt 2$. I don't see how this follows.  Shouldn't it be $1 \lt | (z-2)| \lt 3$ because if z = 4.9999... the resulting value still lies within the circle. Aren't we looking for values of z such that (z-2) lie within the circle?

Comment: What were you told about the interval $0 \lt \left | (z-2) \right | \lt 2$ ? If the radius is larger than 2 the disk will contain 0.

Comment: I am given these facts but I'm trying to figure out what they meant by the interval and where they obtained this from

Comment: What do you mean if the radius were larger than 2 the disk would contain 0? Can you elab?

Comment: The punctured disk $0 \lt \left | (z-2) \right | \lt 2$ does not contain 0, but the punctured disk $0 \lt \left | (z-2) \right | \lt 2+\epsilon$ does contain 0 if $\epsilon>0$.